# Can you get a current users friendlist with facebook API?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I need clarification and the limitations around the changes for Facebook API a year ago. I'm hearing mixed answers!

Can the following happen?

1. User1 signs into the app using facebook login
2. app requests permission to use basic info of user1
3. user1 accepts
4. Additional permission to allow app to see user1 friendlist which user1 accepts
5. assume user1 has 200 friends on facebook
6. app can now display in a list view all 200 of user1 friends (only first name, last name and maybe some form of id)

OR

Can user1 only view his friends also using the app?

OR

Can the app not see any friends if the user has the setting to hide friends on fb?

What are the main practical limitations?

FB API is not descriptive? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/friend-list/

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/friend-list/

Comment: Yeah I posted that link in the question...sounds like that is for customs friendlists though? and not the main one

Comment: Oh sorry didnt saw that.I worked on facebook api about 6 months ago.As far as I remember facebook does not give friend list.It gives friends that uses the same application

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_friends

Comment: see the duplicate question, there is an answer that will tell you exactly under what circumstances you can get all friends.